# My laptop is using secondary Intel GPU instead of Nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, opengl

I have Kubuntu 19.10 with 5.3.0-40-generic Kernel
first GPU - NVIDIA GeForce 920MX
second GPU - Intel HD Graphics 520

When I'm trying to launch Nvidia X settings with command
`sudo nvidia-settings` I get an error:

```
ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

I ran `nvidia-smi` and everything seems fine: `NVIDIA-SMI 440.33.01    Driver Version: 440.33.01    CUDA Version: 10.2`

Then i tried `lspci | grep VGA` and I got `00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 (rev 0a)`

`sudo prime-select nvidia` gave me `Info: the nvidia profile is already set`

```
glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer*"
```

gave me this:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 520 (Skylake GT2)
```

When I'm trying to launch

```
optirun glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"
```

I get this error

```
[ 1920.703346] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
[ 1920.703398] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

Comment: Did you disable Secure Boot?

Comment: No i didn't but it should be disabled, wait i will check it

Comment: it is disabled.

Comment: I will try to purge Nvidia and reinstall it from ppa

Comment: nope, same errors...